# Need help removing certain controls

Tags: vb.net

I am in the process of creating blackjack and I use picture boxes. I had Dimmed a new PictureBox named picbox and every time they hit, it creates a new picturebox with their card in it. I am trying to get it to when they click a button to get a new hand, it deletes all of the picture boxes I created and clears the four that i had originally on there. I cant figure it out.. I tried using Controls.Remove(picbox) but it only removed one of them. Here is my code for the Hit Button:

```
Private Sub HitButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles HitButton.Click

        HitCard = DeckoCards.PlayingCard.GetCards(deck, 1).Item(0)

        With picbox
            .Height = 201
            .Width = 125
        End With
        If PlayerTurn = 1 Then
            Controls.Add(picbox)

            DeckoCards.RealDeck.RealCards(HitCard, picbox)
            picbox.Top = PlayerOneCard2PictureBox.Top
            picbox.Left = xPosPlay1
            xPosPlay1 += 40
            picbox.BringToFront()
            picbox = New PictureBox


        ElseIf PlayerTurn = 2 Then

            Controls.Add(picbox)

            DeckoCards.RealDeck.RealCards(HitCard, picbox)
            picbox.Top = PlayerOneCard2PictureBox.Top
            picbox.Left = xPosPlay2
            xPosPlay2 += 40
            picbox.BringToFront()

        End If

    End Sub
```

Comment: Rather than the hassle of creating and removing controls, why not just add them in the designer and make them invisible when you dont need them?

Comment: oohhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh. Tank u